# Why my C++ code is not taking input ? What's wrong with my code?

Tags: c++, loops, vector

I am currently learning C++ and completely newbie to programming. I came across a question and tried solving but ended up with an undesired output. Then with the help of python tutor I tried visualizing the execution of my code , where even after running **cin >> q** it isn't taking input and displaying an error while executing the next statement where in I tried using the **q**.

Please, Can anyone tell where is the problem and what makes such errors occur?

[Click here to see the problem I tried solving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaDiu.png)

[My C++ Code](https://ideone.com/Q5Pn1H)

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int q,t1,t2;
    vector<int> v;
    cin>>q;
    while(q--){
        if(cin >> t1>>t2){
            if(t1==0)
            {
                v.push_back(t2);
            }
            else if(t1==1)
            {
                cout << v[t2] <<"\n";
            }
        }
        else if(cin >> t1){
            if(t1==2)
            v.pop_back();
        }
        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Error I got while visualizing my code in python tutor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XirSE.png)

Comment: I've no idea what python tutor is but that error message is bogus. Just ignore it.

Comment: When your code says `cin >> q;` what makes you think that `cin` isn't working? What's your evidence? I mean I can see why your program has bugs, but I can't see why `cin` would not be working. Can you explain why you think that is?

Comment: Got to know through visualizing the execution of code in  http://www.pythontutor.com/ .

Comment: Please , Can you then tell why isn't my code working properly?

Comment: Because you have a misunderstanding about how `cin` works. See answer below.

Comment: Well based on the evidence you've provided it's not a very good tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you mean when you say that `cin` isn't working. There's nothing in your code that would make it not work.

However your code has bugs. This code

```
    if(cin >> t1>>t2){
        if(t1==0)
        {
            v.push_back(t2);
        }
        else if(t1==1)
        {
            cout << v[t2] <<"\n";
        }
    }
    else if(cin >> t1){
        if(t1==2)
        v.pop_back();
    }
```

assumes that you can try to read two numbers from a line, and if that doesn't work go back and try and read one number from the same line. `cin` doesn't work like that, if you write `cin >> t1>>t2` the program will read two numbers, from as many lines as it needs to in order to find two numbers.

Here's how to write the code correctly.

```
cin >> t1;
if (t1 == 0)
{
    cin >> t2;
    v.push_back(t2);
}
else if (t1 == 1)
{
    cin >> t2;
    cout << v[t2] <<"\n";
}
else if (t1 == 2)
{
    v.pop_back();
}
```

See how that works? Read the first number, and then read the second number separately if you need to. With this code you can still enter both numbers on the same line if that's what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

From test input provided by Ala in her links, which is:

```
8
0 1
0 2
0 3
2
0 4
1 0
1 1
1 2
```

correct output should be

```
1
2
4
```

Her program above yields `2` instead.
This is because each occurrence of `\n` and `cin` in the code flushes the buffer of `cout`, and the output gets printed while the user still inputs numbers.

To avoid this, and to get all the output at end program, we can just push the output in a second `vector`, and then `cout` its contents at the end:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int q,t1,t2;
    vector<int> v, w;
    cin >> q;
    while(q--){
        cin >> t1;
        if (t1 == 0)
        {
            cin >> t2;
            v.push_back(t2);
        }
        else if (t1 == 1)
        {
            cin >> t2;
            w.push_back(v[t2]);   // new
        }
        else if (t1 == 2)
            v.pop_back();
    }

    // new
    for (int i = 0; i != v.size(); ++i)
        cout << w[i] << endl;

return 0;
}
```

This will yield the correct output.